# Laravel Registration System not feeding data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have a login/registration system I am looking to build in Laravel. Currently I am having trouble pulling the information from the form and inputting it into the table. When I submit the form it submits, but the data goes nowhere, I am admittedly new to Laravel.

This is how the form is written:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
@if (Session::get("error"))
  {{ Session::get("error") }}<br />
@endif
{{ Form::label("first_name", "First Name") }}
{{ Form::text("first_name") }}
{{ $errors->first("first_name") }}<br />
{{ Form::label("email", "Email") }}
{{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }}
{{ $errors->first("email") }}<br />
{{ Form::label("password", "Password") }}
{{ Form::password("password") }}
{{ $errors->first("password") }}<br />
{{ Form::label("password_confirmation", "Confirm") }}
{{ Form::password("password_confirmation") }}
{{ $errors->first("password_confirmation") }}<br />
{{ Form::submit("register") }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The user.register (part of a larger controller) which this POSTs to and GETs from is as follows:

```
public function register()
{
return View::make("user/register");

     $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
     if ($validation->fails())
   {
      return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
   }
      $users = new User;
      $users->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
      $users->email = Input::get('email');
      $users->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
      if ($users->save())
   {
      Auth::loginUsingId($users->id);
      return Redirect::to('profile');
   }
      return Redirect::to('register')-withInput();
   }
}
```

Currently when I submit I get no errors simply a blank redirect to the registration page and nothing ends up in my DB. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my paths? The only other page that is similar to this that I have previously worked on (inputting data to a database) is a page to reset passwords (which works great), but that used a slightly different system through the `Auth` extension of Laravel.

This I am not familiar with. Can someone point me in the right direction? I have been compiling the knowledge I have gained from guides online but keep ending up in the same place!

Thanks a lot in advance,
Anything else you need (models, routes, etc. I just didn't think they were necessary) lemme know!

Comment: If you get a blank page - its probably a 'white screen of death' - and you need to debug the controller function to work out why

Comment: @TheShiftExchange sorry, not a blank screen, a blank form. The registration form reloads blank.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
return Redirect::to('register')-withInput();
```

to

```
return Redirect::to('register')->withInput();
```

edit:

oh - here is the problem:

```
public function register()
{
return View::make("user/register");

     $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
     ...
```

remove the "return" function - it should be

```
public function register()
{
     $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
     ...
```

Comment: Seemed to do the same thing still. Thanks, though!

Comment: Second suggestion breaks it unfortunately. I point my `GET` route at the same controller/view. I'm wondering if I should split them?

Comment: Yes - they must be split. Currently you are forcibliy returning from the first line - which means the rest of your code is *never* run. So when the user submits their form it just returns to the page, because that is what you have told it to do!